# http parallel requests don't work

Tags: angular, observable

I have a piece of code in angular4 where http request is called multiple times before previous call has returned the data, something like this:

```
this.http.put(url, data).subscribe(res => console.log('response data here'));
```

Imagine this line is called twice and second time is called before subscribe is called. I was expecting to have 'response data here' logged twice but it is only showing one time when second request is finished.

Is that expected? Do I need to wait until there is a response from the first call and only then call it second time? If so this is very surprising to me since I was expecting http request could work concurrently.

Thoughts

Comment: You would have to show your actual code than just a single line. What is this *second* call you are talking about? Where's the code for the parallel request?

Comment: sometimes for put and post request options request called. But if you put request calls twice then i think somehow your function is executing twice